# How can i use TO_CHAR method in hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate Criteria to get all rows from a table.

I want a specific row gets formatted like `24,555.00`.

SQL query to get something like this

```
select TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AMT_TRNS, '999,999,999,999.00') 
from deductions
```

I want same TO_CHAR method in Criteria to get formatted column.

Comment: Formatting values like that should be done in the presentation layer of your application, not when retrieving the data. What's wrong with doing that inside Java?

Comment: hi Thanks for your comment. is there is any way that @Annotate TO_CHAR method in variable declared inside pojo ...pls reply...

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can really inject that into a criteria query, unless you've mapped this field in the entity you're querying.

You can achieve what you're trying to do with a `@Formula`

`@Formula` is basically a new field in an entity, but not necessarily mapped to a column in the DB, in your case the mapping will look something like this:

```
@Formula("TO_CHAR(totalAmtTrans, '999,999,999,999.00')") // Note that you're referring to other fields' names and not the column names while writing a criteria, although it's regular SQL in every other regard
private String totalAmtTransFormatted;
```